# How to write a query to get 1 row each based on 3 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table Employee

```
create table emp(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  age int,
  salary int
);
```

Total rows:

```
id  name    age salary
1   Tom     22  2000
2   Mike    12  2000
3   Niki    42  2000
4   Tom     22  2000
5   Yuki    52  2000
6   Niki    42  2000
```

Here in this table, there are 2 employees (Tom and Niki) with same name, age and salary.

Is there any query which i can write to get below output (In case of matching of name, age and salary, i should get row with minimum id).

```
id  name    age salary
1   Tom     22  2000
2   Mike    12  2000
3   Niki    42  2000
5   Yuki    52  2000
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint: `Distinct`.

Comment: Group by the columns you mentioned, then MIN(id)

Comment: @computercarguy distinct doesnt give you the min ID

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, good point. I didn't think about them needing the `id` at all, since that wouldn't work with the `Distinct` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by name, age, salary` with `min(id)` aggregation :

```
select min(id) as id, name, age, salary
  from emp
 group by name, age, salary
```